# Extend an ActiveAdmin page from gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I've installed a gem which relies on ActiveAdmin. Now I'd like to extend one particular ActiveAdmin Page of that gem. E.g. simply adding one new column or field

So if that ActiveAdmin Page is registered like

```
module GemModule
  ActiveAdmin.register Post do
    index do
      column :title
    end
  end
end
```

Is there any way to add another column to index?
Same question for `form.inputs`

Comment: Whatever the field present in your `posts` table will automatically displayed there. If you want to add a custom column then add `column :xyz` below that. but this `xyz` must be define either in model or index action in controller.